# How to map a remote function to a variable length iterable returned by a remote function?

Tags: python, ray

I have a remote function that "splits" an input and returns an iterable.

I'd like to then map a remote function over this returned iterable  (which is an `ObjectID` when constructing the graph).  Something like this:

```py
import ray

@ray.remote
def split(string):
    return string.split('-')

@ray.remote
def process(substring):
    print('Working on', substring)

ray.init()
substrings = split.remote('some-variable-length-string')
for item in substrings:
    process.remote(item)
```

Obviously, that doesn't work (`TypeError: 'ray._raylet.ObjectID' object is not iterable`).  What is the recommended way to do this?  This split-map-reduce is a common pattern in pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

Ray remote functions return object references which are [futures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises). This is important because it lets you do other things while the remote function is running in parallel. This means you're trying to iterate over a promise of a list, not the actual list itself. You need to call `ray.get` in order to actually get the list.

You also have a second similar bug in your code. Since `process.remote` will also run in parallel, it isn't guaranteed to finish before the rest of our program finishes, therefor we need to call ray.get on all of those references in order to make sure those tasks finish before the program ends.

```
import ray

@ray.remote
def split(string):
    return string.split('-')

@ray.remote
def process(substring):
    print('Working on', substring)

ray.init()
substrings_ref = split.remote('some-variable-length-string')
process_refs = []
for item in ray.get(substrings):
    process_refs.append(process.remote(item))
ray.get(process_refs) # Notice the ray.get here too
```